Android transition using shared element from RecycleViewer
Iam trying to implement a transition between two fragments using a shared element. FragmentA has a RecycleViewer which hosts entries. Each entry has a button when clicked, transitiones the entry to FragmentB where the entry is editable. This transition works as expected however Iam unable to achive the transition when calling popBackStack() to transition the element back into the RecycleViewer in FragmentA.
This is my FragmentA which hosts the RecyleViewer:
class FragmentA : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentABinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentCreateBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        ...

        return binding.root
    }
}

This is the AdapterClass for the Entries:
class Adapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private var entries: MutableList<Entry>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.entry, parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        
        ...

        holder.itemView.transitionName = "entry_$position"

        holder.button.setOnClickListener {
            
            val fragmentManager = (context as AppCompatActivity).supportFragmentManager
            val editFragment = FragmentB()

            val bundle = Bundle()
            bundle.putInt("entryPosition", position)
            editFragment.arguments = bundle

            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .addSharedElement(holder.itemView, holder.itemView.transitionName)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .replace(R.id.fragmentContainerView, editFragment)
                .commit()
        }
    }
}

And this is FragmentB which is used to edit entries:
class FragmentB : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentBBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentEditFlagBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)

        binding.entry.root.transitionName = "entry_${arguments?.getInt("entryPosition")}"
        
        ...
        

        binding.saveButton.setOnClickListener {
            requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.popBackStack()
        }
        
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        sharedElementEnterTransition = MaterialContainerTransform().apply {
            duration = 500
            scrimColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
        }

        sharedElementReturnTransition = MaterialContainerTransform().apply {
            duration = 500
            scrimColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
        }
    }
}

I have read the documentation and especially this part is what I think I need. I tried posponing the animation as I think I need to wait until all views when entering FRagmentA have been measured and laid, especially the Recycleviewer.
class FragmentA : Fragment() {
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        postponeEnterTransition()

        viewModel.data.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            adapter.setData(it)
            (view.parent as? ViewGroup)?.doOnPreDraw {
                startPostponedEnterTransition()
            }
        }
    }
}

I also tried setting a sharedElementEnterTransition for FragmentA and also gave each entry a unique ID but it also does seem not help and I think the position Iam using should be sufficient as Iam not changing the list of my entries from my FragmentB.

I solved this by adding .setReorderingAllowed(true) to the transaction and in FragmentA and postponing the transition till the PreDrawListener fires.
